# What about running YOLOv3-tiny on stm32H7?

Tags: stm32, object-detection, yolo

ATT.What do you think is the hard part?In some application scenarios where the real-time and precision requirements are not high, I think this is very meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if any machine learning packages you use support the instruction sets of this processor. If a library such as tensorflow or ml.net doesn't support it then the hardest part would be creating the infrastructure for a baseline neural network to run, forget coding up the loss function and bounding boxes.